# Laravel - WebSockets how to trigger even from client to server via websocket connection

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I am using Laravel and I have installed https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction.

So far so good. I have created my first event:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('home');
    }
}
```

When on server I trigger the event like this:

```
event(new App\Events\NewMessage("Hello World"))
```

On the client side I use Laravel Echo to listen for the event and print the result in the console like this:

```
<script>
    Echo.channel('home')
    .listen('NewMessage', (e)=> {
        console.log(e.message);
    })

    function SendTestMessage(){
        console.log("Test");
        Echo.channel('home').trigger('NewMessage',{ message: 'TEST Alarm!' });
    }
</script>
```

This works all fine. When I trigger on the server the even I see immediately on the console in the client the message.

However I would like to make a trigger of even from the client to the server **WITHOUT** rest POST api request. I would like to trigger the even via the websocket connection.

So I tried to make the following function in JS:

```
function SendTestMessage(){
    console.log("Test");
    Echo.channel('home').trigger('NewMessage',{ message: 'TEST Alarm!' });
}
```

However this thing does not trigger an event to the server. Why is that and how can I trigger even via the websocket communication?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: what is your motivation to trigger events on frontend via websocket?, Laravel Websocket can receive rest request but it most be with a valid headers and correct auth credentials else it will be ignored. read about the pusher protocol

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable in `config/websockets.php`

```
'enable_client_messages' => true,
```

refer to this doc https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/events/#triggering-client-events
then from client side

```
var triggered = channel.trigger(eventName, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the internals of Laravel Websocket with path name specifically `vendor\beyondcode\laravel-websockets\src\HttpApi\Controllers\TriggerEventController.php`

which is responsible for accepting events, it is not connected to accept websocket request, only http request, so you can't trigger an event using websocket protocol in laravel websocket, if that was your question.

To confirm this look into the `vendor\beyondcode\laravel-websockets\src\Server\Router.php`

```
public function echo()
{
    $this->get('/app/{appKey}', WebSocketHandler::class);

    $this->post('/apps/{appId}/events', TriggerEventController::class);
    $this->get('/apps/{appId}/channels', FetchChannelsController::class);
    $this->get('/apps/{appId}/channels/{channelName}', FetchChannelController::class);
    $this->get('/apps/{appId}/channels/{channelName}/users', FetchUsersController::class);
}
```

You will notice that aside from `/app/{appkey}` route which handles all Socket request, all other route container only has the __invoke() method, which means they don't expect socket request, they only expect REST request and when it comes, the request must have valid signature header which can only be provided by the backend service. it will be a security flaw to have this token as part of your frontend codes. So backend stands as the gateway to trigger this event.

Simply send the appropriate RESTful request to your typical laravel backend controller to trigger your desired event internally and it will trigger it. which is what one of the answer is suggesting and which is advisable. I think there is an internal implementation for it, although can only be triggered by logged in users through private channels or presence channel which is advisable too and it involves RESTful process

Here is the valid signatures you will be needing if you were to send a RESTful request to laravel Websocket package directly without going through laravel backend. looking closely, it uses hmac to verify signature. Signature can only be made or verified using the a security app key only known to backend and laravel websocket.

```
protected function ensureValidSignature(Request $request)
{
    /*
     * The `auth_signature` & `body_md5` parameters are not included when calculating the `auth_signature` value.
     *
     * The `appId`, `appKey` & `channelName` parameters are actually route paramaters and are never supplied by the client.
     */
    $params = Arr::except($request->query(), ['auth_signature', 'body_md5', 'appId', 'appKey', 'channelName']);

    if ($request->getContent() !== '') {
        $params['body_md5'] = md5($request->getContent());
    }

    ksort($params);

    $signature = "{$request->getMethod()}\n/{$request->path()}\n".Pusher::array_implode('=', '&', $params);

    $authSignature = hash_hmac('sha256', $signature, App::findById($request->get('appId'))->secret);

    if ($authSignature !== $request->get('auth_signature')) {
        throw new HttpException(401, 'Invalid auth signature provided.');
    }

    return $this;
}
```

this can be found in  `vendor\beyondcode\laravel-websockets\src\HttpApi\Controllers\Controller.php` which is the abstract class extended by all non-websocket endpoint.

I hope this helps